# Soft question - some interesting pde applications in "real life"

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, applications

I have to do a final project for my PDE subject and I'm looking for some interesting applications. The idea is to discuss a problem and it's related model, then possibly find a  solution. I have to explain it to my teacher and my course mates in about 30-40 minutes.

Until now we have seen first order PDEs (both linear and non-linear) and second order (hyperbolic, parabolic and elliptic) PDEs. Also wave equation and heat equation.

What would be some "fun" PDE related problems to discuss?
Any idea would be really appreciated! :-)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262046/589 and https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/applying-modern-pde-techniques-to-digital-image-restoration.html

Comment: Maybe this topic would be interesting (connection between structural mechanics and quantum mechanics) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/218983/94257

Comment: The most interesting PDE application in "real life": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier_Stokes_Equations